# Getting the 'does not exist in the current context' in watch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to watch a variable declared as type var in VS2015 while debugging and I get an error The name 'connString' does not exist in the current context"

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:AppContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

The screenshot [image]

Comment: Is it debug build or release build?

Comment: @qxg it's in debug

Comment: What do you have in local and auto window?

Comment: @qxg I noticed this happens for all variables that are declared as type var